# Multiple paramater based routes for an API Endoint in an Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I have a simple Function App in Azure that returns data in JSON.

[https://myurl.com/api/symbolcountry/{id}](https://myurl.com/api/symbolcountry/%7Bid%7D)?

It takes in a single id for a parameter. It works well.

However I'd like to parameterize part of the url

[https://myurl.com/api/{endpoint}/{id}](https://myurl.com/api/%7Bendpoint%7D/%7Bid%7D)?

I've never messed around with javascript and am going a bit nuts trying to figure this one out.

function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],      
      "route": "symbolcountry/{id}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.js file:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {    
    const method = req.method.toLowerCase();
    var payload = null;
    var entity = "";


    switch(method) {
        case "get":
            if (req.params.id) {                
                entity = "symbolcountry"                                      
                payload = { "SymbolID": req.params.id};  
            } 
            else {                
                entity = "symbols"                
            }
            break;    
    }

}
```

Tried adding paramters in function.json to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to access the params passed in the URL instead of `params`  use the key work `query`

Your code will look like this:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const  metthod = req.method.toLowerCase();
    var payload = null;
    var entity = "";
    switch(metthod)
    {
        case "get" : if(req.query.id)
                  {
                      entity="symbolcountry";
                      payload = {
                                    "SymbolId":req.query.id 
                                }
                  }
                  break;
    }
    context.res = {
            body = payload
        }
```

The above code will return the payload

output :
[image]

If you want to parameters through routing, you can refer this [article](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-http-route-parameters-in-azure-functions-2x-using-python-k2k3qxz#:%7E:text=HTTP%20Route%20Parameters-,Let%E2%80%99s%20walk%20through%20an,your%20function.json%20file:,-%22route%22:%20%22FirstNameLastName/%7Bfirstname) by JOE GATT